# std::sort() on a vector of Class pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, stl-algorithm

I have a vector of class pointers `std::vector<Square*> listSquares`. I want to sort it with one of the attributes of the class as the key. This is what I'm doing

```
bool compById(Square* a, Square* b)
{
    return a->getId() < b->getId();
}

std::sort(listSquares.begin(), listSquares.end(), compById)
```

but the compiler says:
error: no matching function for call to 'sort(std::vector::iterator, std::vector::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you can use C++11, you should make this a lambda: `std::sort(listSquares.begin(), listSquares.end(), [](Square* a, Square* b){return a->getId() < b->getId;})`.

Comment: Make sure you actually want pointers and not just objects, too.

Comment: I can't use C++11.
@chris I'm sure I want to use pointers.

Comment: @qutab have you declared compById inside a class or outside? It should be outside.

Comment: @john, I've declared it inside the class as a private member function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to use `compById` as a parameter to `std::sort` it should not be a member function. This is wrong

```
class Square
{
    bool compById(Square* a, Square* b)
    {
        return a->getId() < b->getId();
    }
    ...
};
```

This is better,

```
class Square
{
    ...
};

bool compById(Square* a, Square* b)
{
    return a->getId() < b->getId();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was the problem. But why can't we declare it as a member function? Actually I'm using it in a different class than square itself.

Comment: Because how would std::sort know which object to use when it calls the member function? Member functions can only be called on objects, but std::sort has no context to determine which object that should be. Presumably you are calling std::sort from inside some object, but you aren't passing that object to std::sort. std::sort knows nothing about where it's being called from, all it knows are the three parameters you pass to it.

Comment: It can  be a static member function. A normal (non-static) member function takes an implicit first argument, a.k.a 'this', and hence has a different signature than a non-member function.

Answer (score 3):

The most important part you're missing is that the arguments to the compare function are `const`. Another is the return type. If you leave out the return type when declaring a function, the compiler will assume it returns `int` which is not correct in this case.

And of course the comparison function has to be in scope when you call the `std::sort` function.

Comment: Even if I use const, I get the same error. In this case I also get,
 gameplay.cpp:911: error: passing 'const Square' as 'this' argument of 'int Square::getId()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: @qutab, you have to make getId() a const member function, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a member function. But you need to define it as a static member function and call it from the class, not an instance of the class.

Notice `static` before the function declaration, and `Square::` before the function name in sort.

```
class Square
{
    /*...*/
public:
    static bool compById(const Square* a, const Square* b)
    {
        return a->getId() < b->getId();
    }
};

main()
{
    /*...*/
    std::sort(listSquares.begin(), listSquares.end(), Square::compById);
}
```