# C++, using std::sort on a vector of class pointers - OR I can't name my functions properly

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

**Actual Problem:** I named my function 'sort', and it called sort without specifying std, and now I feel dumb.

**Solution:** Rename my function and explicitly invoke std::sort from now on (like everyone but my professors advise me to do).

I'm trying to figure out std::sort by sorting a vector(cat) of class (Song) pointers based upon strings in that class.

I'm specifically trying to adapt this solution [std::sort() on a vector of Class pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366978/stdsort-on-a-vector-of-class-pointers), but without success.

The best I've been able to come up with is:

```
void Catalog::sort()
{
       sort(cat.begin(), cat.end(), compareTitle );
       return;
}
bool compareTitle(Song* a, Song* b)
{
        return(a->getTitle().compare(b->getTitle()) < 0);
}
```

Here compareTitle is not a class function. Compiler returns

```
catalog.cpp: In member function ‘void Catalog::sort()’:
catalog.cpp:62:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘Catalog::sort(std::vector<Song*>::iterator, std::vector<Song*>::iterator, bool (&)(Song*, Song*))’
   62 |  sort(cat.begin(), cat.end(), compareTitle );
      |                                            ^
catalog.cpp:59:6: note: candidate: ‘void Catalog::sort()’
   59 | void Catalog::sort()
      |      ^~~~~~~
catalog.cpp:59:6: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 3 provided
```

I have also tried

```
void Catalog::sort()
{
      sort(cat.begin(), cat.end(), [](Song* a, Song* b){
           return(a->getTitle().compare(b->getTitle()) < 0);
           });
        return;
}
```

Which gives me

```
catalog.cpp: In member function ‘void Catalog::sort()’:
catalog.cpp:66:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘Catalog::sort(std::vector<Song*>::iterator, std::vector<Song*>::iterator, Catalog::sort()::<lambda(Song*, Song*)>)’
   66 |     } );
      |       ^
catalog.cpp:59:6: note: candidate: ‘void Catalog::sort()’
   59 | void Catalog::sort()
      |      ^~~~~~~
catalog.cpp:59:6: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 3 provided
```

Any advice is appreciated; my searches have not been fruitful.

Comment: maybe you forgot "using namespace std; " or "#include <algirithm>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are struggling with how name lookup works. In `Catalog::sort`, when you use the non-qualified `sort`, the compiler comes up with `Catalog::sort` again - the member functions tries to calls itself. But as the function signature doesn't match, the compiler complains.

You can fix this by explicitly prefixing your call, i.e.

```
std::sort(cat.begin(), cat.end(),
    [](const Song *lhs, const Song *rhs) { /* ... */ });
```

Note that the lambda here is the way to go, passing a member function pointer (as in your first example) won't work like this.

Last, make sure that the `<algorithm>` header is included.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, you want to call `std::sort()`, but you making a call that doesn't qualify *which* `sort()` you want, so the compiler sees the nearest `sort()` is `Catalog::sort()` and tries to call it again, but fails since the parameters do not match.

Put `std::` in front of the call, eg:

```cpp
void Catalog::sort()
{
    std::sort(...);
}
```

That being said, in both examples, whether you use a function or a lambda for your `std::sort()` predicate, its `return` statement can be simplified to this:

```cpp
return a->getTitle() < b->getTitle();
```

The predicate is expected to return `true` if the 1st parameter is "less than" the 2nd parameter.  Assuming `getTitle()` returns a `std::string`, its native `operator<` returns that exact result for you.  There is no need to call `compare()` manually.